# Using path parameters on an Azure API legacy SOAP service

Tags: soap, azure-api-management

We are looking at using the Azure API management service to host a legacy SOAP service. We need the API to be multi-tenanted and I am trying to use the URL to differentiate between customers. I have successfully imported the WSDL file and can call the appropriate service with the default URL.

What I am trying to accomplish to use a URL in the following format

[https://mysoapapi.domain.com/service/{customer}](https://mysoapapi.domain.com/service/%7Bcustomer%7D)

I then want to extract the customer from the URL before performing the actions required (Azure function in my case)

So customer A might access the service using https://mysoapapi.domain.com/service/custa
And customer B will use the following URL https://mysoapapi.domain.com/service/custb

But both URL will call the same Azure Function.

I did try changing the FrontEnd URL to include the parameter leaving the soapAction query paramerer on the end but for the error "SOAP Operation URL should conating action as '/?soapAction=..."

Is this possible using a SOAP api.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use Wildcard SOAP Action, refer https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/api-management/import-soap-api.md#wildcard-soap-action